# ImportError : cannot import name '_win32stdio'

Tags: python, visual-studio, scrapy

I am working with Scrapy framework to scrap out data from website, but getting the following error in command prompt:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'

Traceback is attached as a screenshot.

Kindly revert if require directory structure of my program's directory.

[image: Error in CMD]

Comment: [Similar issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1998) was opened the other day on Scrapy issue tracker. [Bottom line](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1998#issuecomment-220305203) is that, unfortunately, `twisted.internet._win32stdio` does not work on Windows with Python 3, so scrapy can't run either on Windows with Python 3

Comment: Then what should be done i mean any alternatives , does it run with newer version of python or older ones

Comment: @paul trmbrth from following URL http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html i found this: What Python versions does Scrapy support?
Scrapy is supported under Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+. Python 2.6 support was dropped starting at Scrapy 0.20. Python 3 support was added in Scrapy 1.1.

Comment: Is it due to microsoft visual studio version installed ?

Comment: Correct about Python 3 support starting with 1.1. Although in the release notes, Python 3 support is said to be beta. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#beta-python-3-support says _Scrapy has not been tested on Windows with Python 3_

Comment: Twisted is not related to Scrapy. But Scrapy relies on it at its heart. Twisted is not fully ported to Python 3 (including this `twisted.internet._win32stdio`). Scrapy should work in Python 2 on Windows.

Comment: @paul can you suggest any alternative for scrapy for python 3.4

Comment: Apart from running scrapy in a Linux virtual machine, you could try another scraping framework like [PySpider](http://docs.pyspider.org/) (but I never tried them on Windows, nor on Python 3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scrapy can work with Python 3 on windows if you make some minor adjustments:

1. Copy the _win32stdio and _pollingfile to the appropriate directory under site-packages. Namely, twisted-dir\internet. Download these from https://github.com/twisted/twisted/tree/trunk/twisted/internet
2. `pip install pypiwin32`

Granted, this is based on my personal experience. Because the repository will certainly change in the future, readers should beware the age of this answer.

Update: the `twisted-win` package is no longer required because the appropriate files are now included in the `twisted` package.

Comment: _pollingfile is not present in site_packages folder

Comment: You need to download these files from the twisted repository. I have also made a `twisted-win` pypi package that will copy these files for you.

Comment: `pip install twisted-win` fixed this for me.

Comment: still getting the same error if possible have a look at the screenshot which i have attached.

Comment: pip install twisted-win worked, for me easy solution.

Comment: `twisted-win` works for me. Probably you should add that to the answer if @enthus1ast agree with that.

Comment: Of course, it think  @xaav is the creator of this package, credits should go to him!

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through the same. I have resolved by updating the twisted package

`pip install --upgrade twisted` 
                 
 or 
`pip uninstall twisted` and `pip install twisted`

Answer (score 0):

get whl of twisted (from below link) according to your os and py version and you are good to go!
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted