# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'"? Typical solutions at a roadblock

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to overcome a *seemingly* answered question, but none of the provided solutions are enough.

Specifically, I am trying to create a ScraPy crawler, but when I use `"scrapy crawl myProjectsName"`, I get:

`ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'`

Now, that would be fine, given that the question already has a solution posted here on stackoverflow:

[ImportError : cannot import name '_win32stdio'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342603/importerror-cannot-import-name-win32stdio) (Link to previous solution)

But it's not working out for me:

When I write `"pip install twisted"` or the alternative solution (seen elsewhere on the web), `"pip install pywin32"`, both result in the following error msg from my terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied: twisted in c:\users\roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (16.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.0.2 in c:\users\roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (4.2.0)
```

Here is a link to some (but not all -- it was very long...) of the traceback shown in terminal

https://i.stack.imgur.com/itUKh.jpg

My expected result is a functional output from my scrapy web crawler. But the output is an ImportError.

I believe the solution is probably as simple as copy and pasting something from here to there, since the contents appear to already be on my computer. I just don't know where to put them.

Note/P.S.: I presume I could sort this out on my own if I knew how to read the traceback info, is that right? If you've figured out a solution to my issue, how did you know what it was?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to download twisted-win from github: https://github.com/twisted/twisted

Then copy _win32stdio and _pollingfile to the directory where it was missing.

Now it works!